# Resetting backbone.js attributes hash

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I've created a model in backbone:

```
var app={};
app.pilot_id = $("#user_id").val();   
app.Pilot = Backbone.Model.extend({    
url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'pilotdata/v1/pilot/',   
sync: function(method, model, options) {
    return Backbone.sync(method, this, $.extend(options, {
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader ('X-WP-NONCE', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce);
     }
  }))   
},
defaults : {
    lastName: 'Doe', 
    firstName: 'John'
},
initialize : function() {
  this.fetch({ data: ({id: app.pilot_id})});
 }
});
```

`app.pilot = new app.Pilot();` 
{ after the fetch lastName will be 'Smith' and firstName will be 'Sue'

and I create a view with backform.js

```
app.PilotForm =  Backform.Form.extend({
el: $("#personalInformation"),
events: {
    "submit": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();this.model.save( {patch: true})
    .done(function(req, status, err) {
        alert( status + ', ' + err);
        console.log(status, err);
    })  
    .fail(function(req, status, err) {
        alert( status + ', ' + err);
    });
      return false;
    }
 },
 fields: [
   {name: "id", label: "Id", control: "uneditable-input"},
   {name: "firstName", label: "First Name", control: "input"},
   {name: "lastName", label: "Last Name", control: "input"},
   {control: "button", label: "Save to server"}
 ],});
  new app.PilotForm({model: app.pilot}).render();
```

This is going to be a multi-page form. And only a few fields will need to be updated each time. So I would like to update the server with "PATCH" However ALL of the fields that have been pre-filled from the fetch are flagged at changed. Therefore everything is sent in the PATCH request.

After creating the new app.PilotForm... I've added

```
app.pilot.attributes={};
```

This does work; now when I change a field only that field is sent in the PATCH request. However, the documentation suggests it is bad to mess directly with the attributes hash. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use model method such as `changedAttributes`, `previousAttributes` etc to find the info you want to send to the server and then use that `patch` option of [`model.save`](https://backbonejs.org/#Model-save):

> If instead, you'd only like the changed attributes to be sent to the server, call `model.save(attrs, {patch: true})`. You'll get an HTTP PATCH request to the server with just the passed-in attributes.

Where `attrs` is whatever you want to be the payload

Comment: The problem is previousAttributes contains all of my default values. ALL attributes are in the changedAttributes hash because they were loaded from the server with fetch. What I want is just the attributes that have been changed by the user. it appears to me the only way to do that is to flush the attributes hash.

Comment: "*ALL attributes are in the changedAttributes hash because they were loaded from the server with fetch*"

This is not true. Changed attributes is basically "*Retrieve a hash of only the model's attributes that have changed since the last `set`, or false if there are none*".

If you are doing multiple `set` in client side then maybe you need to keep track of what you are changing since the fetch in an array or something, I don't see why you would want to "flush" attributes hash or what it even means

Comment: Ok, nevermind that, just found this "*Note that this method, and the following change-related ones, are only useful during the course of a "change" event.*"

So it seems you simply need to keep track of changed attributes yourself in the model, something like `modelInstance.changedSinceFetch = ['name', 'lastname']` etc then later just `pluck` these and sent it using `patch` option

Comment: I could keep track of the changes as you say, however if I clear the attributes hash, it is all done for me. So what is the problem with that?

Comment: @magic Maybe if the save fails you want original values? are you the only person working on this project? Nobody will expect such behaviour and who knows what backbone api expectations will break. It's your project so it is your decision to make.

Comment: Good point, for now I am the only one and I need to get this working today. I'll include some "Notes to future self" and re-visit it in version 1.2 . if save fails, the original values are already in the database.